# Variable table name in BigQuery Python Client

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

Having seen the correct format for the setting of variables for sql queries, I'm not finding a similar way to parameterise the table name. For example, I have a simple query as follows

```
query = """
    select price, category, title, sm_title from `product.data_set.table_name` where  
    product = @product"""
    
    
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("product", "INT64", product),
    ])
    
    
    product_data = client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
```

I would like the `table_name` to be a variable that can be passed in. Is there can option that can be used like is set in the job_config?

Comment: To my knowledge no.  This would get into dynamic SQL.  you could dynamically set it as part of building your query string, but the SQL passed to the database must have a defined table name which isn't variable.  the engine's haven't been built to allow for a "Dynamic" table since tables have rigid structures defined.  Each table could/should be different so why would one want a dynamic table name... different table is a different query consisting of different objects entirely.  If the tables are that similar, why not use a type to filter the like data and a parameter works...

Comment: cant you do that with string formatting? line 1: `table_name = "tablenamegoeshere"` line 2: `query = f"""
    select price, category, title, sm_title from \`product.data_set.{table_name}\` where  
    product = @product"""`

Comment: Hi OP, have you tried @EdoAkse 's suggestion using f string formatting and confirm if it resolves your concern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting of python variable for SQL query can be done using **python's f string** formatting approach as suggested by @EdoAkse in the comments.

You may use below

```
table_name = "tablenamegoeshere"
query = f""" select price, category, title, sm_title from `product.data_set.{table_name}` where product = @product"""
```

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: Just a word of caution - `table_name` should come from a trusted source to avoid SQL injection risks.

Comment: echoing @plamut - sql injection is bad. Use an ORM or find some official(ish) way to validate the safeness of the variable content. This shouldn't really be an accepted answer without a very big warning to future readers. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp